# xforms rendered via xslt and xml error

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, xslt, xforms

I know this question will sound like a "from the past" thing but I need to do this for a homework and I can't make it work.

The problem the following:

I have xml data, called from a database, I used xslt to render an xforms document on the browser, by the way its the old firefox 3.6 that was installed only to use the xforms extension.
It renders the xforms document correctly, but the controls doesnt work as expected, I cant submit a form and also the instance data is not filling in the inputs.

My xsl stylesheet is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
<xsl:output method="xml"
indent="yes"
omit-xml-declaration="yes"
media-type="application/xhtml+xml"
doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" dir="ltr" lang="es">
        <head>
            <xf:model>
                <xf:instance>
                    <data xmlns="">
                        <iCargo_Id>1</iCargo_Id>
                        <sCargo_Desc>lalala</sCargo_Desc>
                        <iConcurrencia_Id>1</iConcurrencia_Id>
                    </data>
                </xf:instance>
                <xf:submission id="prueba" action="EditarCargos.aspx" method="post"/>
            </xf:model>

            <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <title><![CDATA[Adicionar Cargos]]></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="../empleados/editarempleados.aspx"><![CDATA[Empleados]]></a>
                <a href="../horarios/editarhorarios.aspx"><![CDATA[Horarios]]></a>
                <a href="../jornadas/editarjornadas.aspx"><![CDATA[Jornadas]]></a>
                <a href="../cargos/editarcargos.aspx"><![CDATA[Cargos]]></a>
                <a href="../usuarios/editarusuarios.aspx"><![CDATA[Usuarios]]></a>
                <a href="../profesiones/editarprofesiones.aspx"><![CDATA[Profesiones]]></a>
                <a href="../reportes/ReporteMarcaciones.aspx"><![CDATA[Rep. de Marcaciones]]></a>
                <a href="../cerrarSesion.aspx"><![CDATA[Cerrar Sesión]]></a>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div class="mainTitle">
                    <![CDATA[Adicionar Cargos]]>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <xf:input ref="sCargo_Desc">
                        <xf:label><![CDATA[Cargo]]></xf:label>
                    </xf:input>
                    <div>
                        <xf:submit submission="prueba">
                            <xf:label><![CDATA[Guardar Cambios]]></xf:label>
                        </xf:submit>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>

                    <a class="cmdSecond" href="EditarCargos.aspx"><![CDATA[Volver]]></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cargo[iCargo_Id]">
    <iCargo_Id>
        <xsl:value-of select="iCargo_Id"/>
    </iCargo_Id>
    <sCargo_Desc>
        <xsl:value-of select="sCargo_Desc"/>
    </sCargo_Desc>
    <iConcurrencia_Id>
        <xsl:value-of select="iConcurrencia_Id"/>
    </iConcurrencia_Id>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cargo[not(iCargo_Id)]">
    <iCargo_Id></iCargo_Id>
    <sCargo_Desc></sCargo_Desc>
    <iConcurrencia_Id></iConcurrencia_Id>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my xml code look like this:

```
<cargo>
    <iCargo_Id>1</iCargo_Id>
    <sCargo_Desc>Jefe de Sistemas</sCargo_Desc>
    <iConcurrencia_Id>1</iConcurrencia_Id>
</cargo>
```

I think the problem is the `<xsl:output method="xml"` attribute
, because xforms requires xhtml to render, but firefox throws an XSLT exception when I make it.

please Help! I have searched everywhere, and Ive found It has something to be with a bug in firefox but I expect there's another way to make this work, your help will be very appreciated and sorry about my English, I'm currently learning :D

Comment: There is no such thing as xhtml output. It can either be xml, html, text. Firefox supports html/xml.

Comment: @FailedDev, do you mean there is no `xhtml` output *method* in XSLT 1.0? which is true, but you can output XHTML from XSLT 1.0, since it's XML. So I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: You can try transforming with another XSLT processor -- particularly with an XSLT 2.0 processor where you can specify `<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>` -- then try to see if the produced result has the expected behavior. If this isn't so, then your hypothesis for the cause of the problem is wrong.

Comment: @LarsH Yes that's what I meant :). Of course you can output xhtml.

Comment: @jmacboy: It would be very helpful if you would tell us what exception Firefox throws.

Comment: P.S. I validated your stylesheet using Saxon, and it said the stylesheet is valid. So please specify what you mean by "an XSLT exception".

Comment: Well, the xslt exception i got was when I changed that attribute for xhtml, because xforms needed xhtml and with xml firefox rendered bad xforms, my workaround for this was changing my  XSLT processor, the other processor did the job correctly for the xml attribute and it work fine now, thanks!

Comment: @jmacboy  If you have fixed the problem, please post the solution as an answer, and accept it.  This will remove it from the unanswered list, and help others who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I didnt found a solution but used a workaround to make this work.

As the problem was with Firefox, I had to render the stylesheet in another way, so I used aspnet to pre-render the stylesheet on code behind (I forgot to mention that I was working with it), and then I wrote it to the Page using Response.Write and it worked like a charm using html as the xsl:output method